# How can I prevent accidental execution of the rm -r *command?

Tags: bash, rm

Occasionally I use command to delete some files. For example, the name might start with 'a', so I'll delete with the command `rm -r a*`, but I don't want to remove some other directory by accident.  How can I lock a directory to prevent deletion by `rm -r` ?

Answer (score 5):

You could alias the `rm` command to `rm -i` in your shell, so it will ask your confirmation for each file.

However, some consider this to be harmful. See [*alias rm=“rm -i” considered harmful?*](https://superuser.com/questions/384769/alias-rm-rm-i-considered-harmful) on Superuser.com

Other thoughts are in [*How do I prevent accidental rm -rf /*?*](https://serverfault.com/questions/337082/how-do-i-prevent-accidental-rm-rf) on StackOverflow.com.

Answer (score 2):

The best advice is to grow to fear and respect the 'rm -r' or 'rm -rf' commands enough that, when you type them, you stop yourself and proceed slowly and with caution (reading over the command carefully a few times). The commands are useful and sometimes need to be used - but it's not a good idea to trick the system into saving you from this type of mistake; it's not a good idea to grow accustomed to such workarounds---consider building good habits that can be carried from machine to machine.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to selectively remove items, you can use `find` .

```
find . -name "a*" \! -type d -delete
```

You can check what you are deleting by running:

```
find . -name "a*" \! -type d -print
```

For example, create a some directories and files:

```
mkdir -p testDir/a/b 
cd testDir
touch apple.txt banana.txt ant.tx a/antelope.txt a/bus.txt a/b/apostrophe.txt a/b/bug.txt
```

To see the files and directories:

```
find . -name "*" -print
```

returns:

```
.
./a
./a/antelope.txt
./a/b
./a/b/apostrophe.txt
./a/bus.txt
./ant.tx
./apple.txt
./banana.txt
```

To verify what is being deleted:

```
find . -name "a*" \! -type d -print
```

returns:

```
./a/antelope.txt
./a/b/apostrophe.txt
./ant.tx
./apple.txt
```

To delete the files:

```
find . -name "a*" \! -type d -delete
```

To verify that only a* files have been delete:

```
find . -name "*" -print
```

returns:

```
.
./a
./a/b
./a/bus.txt
./banana.txt
```

Comment: removed my comment. :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers here, I recommend that you use tab completion more and globbing less. From your question, it appears that you're trying to delete a single file but don't want to type the full name. In that case, instead of `*` you should hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Tab completion is much safer.

If you actually do intend to delete multiple files whose name matches a glob, the best way, as already pointed out, is to think twice before hitting enter. In addition, you can gain a lot of peace of mind if you use a backup solution that backs up all changes as you make them so you can always restore any mistake without risk of data loss.